# Entrys wont order correctly

Tags: php, email, mysqli

I've got a 'contact' table in my database which stores the emails people are sending to me. In my adminpanel I'd like to order them by status. My contact table has an 'answered' INT column which updates as soon as I'm replying to them. Once I answered the email, the 'answered' will be set to '1' in the database.

As I said, I'd like to order the emails in my adminpanel by the 'answered' status. So all emails which arnt answered yet ('0' in database) should be on top and the emails I already have answered ('1' in database) should be on the bottom.

This is how I've currently got it:

```
$showTheEmails = array(); 
$getEmails = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY 'answered' ASC") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
if (mysqli_num_rows($getEmails) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getEmails)){
        $row = array( 
        'contact_id' => $row['contact_id'],
        'name' => $row['name'], 
        'email' => $row['email'], 
        'subject' => $row['subject'], 
        'timestamp' => $row['timestamp'], 
        'answered' => $row['answered'] );
        $showTheEmails[] = $row;
    }
}
```

And ofcourse the code what displays the array.

Problem is: it's not ordering correctly. What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: The entire PHP element of this question is not part of the problem, which you could have deduce by running your query directly in a MySQL console. Please post just the query and remove the `php` and `email` tags as they are not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping with single quotes, you've created the problem. You're instructing MySQL to try to order by the word "answered" (rather than the column in the database). Simply remove the quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY answered ASC
```

As pointed out in the comments, you may also surround the column names with `backticks` like

```
SELECT * FROM `contact` ORDER BY `answered` ASC
```

> Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are
>   only necessary when the identifier is a MySQL reserved keyword, or
>   when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters
>   beyond a limited set (see below) It is often recommended to avoid
>   using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible,
>   avoiding the quoting issue.

[When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Lmfao im such a nubcake :')  Thanks man, working perfectly fine now. I'll accept ur answer within' 10 minutes.

Comment: Don't remove the quotes. Replace them with the _correct_ quotes, which is backticks.

Comment: Noting that you still haven't.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY 'answered' ASC
```

The single quotes delimit a *string*; you're essentially giving each record a constant ordering hint, resulting in no ordering at all!

To name a field, use backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY `answered` ASC
```